# Inheriting properties in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, inheritance

I have a custom control that has several text boxes and combo boxes in it. In order for my control to work properly, I need to set the TabIndex on each of the controls to the proper location in the host form. For example, if my control is at TabIndex 2 on the parent form, each control inside it should be set to a TabIndex of 2, and everything works as it should. I am not very good at WPF. My naive solution was to define a public property on my custom control, and have the setter set the TabIndex on each of the subcontrols. I hate this solution.

I'm sure there must be a way to bind properties to whatever is set by the parent control, but I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `RelativeSource` binding directive. Example:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
Path=Title}
```

[msdn information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx), [wpf cheat sheet](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf).

Comment: Ok, the cheat sheet helped me. I actually ended up binding to the tabindex property on the child control's root element. It turned out to be a bit more concise that way. Thanks for the cheat sheet!